MSI B350 gaming plus specification mentioned 128 GB of ram, CP2K32G4DFRA32A RAM not there in compatabilty
MSI B350 gaming plus specification mentions 128GB of RAM, CP2K32G4DFRA32A RAM is not there in the compatibility list.
How can I know, if CP2K32G4DFRA32A is suitable for my Motherboard or not.

We need to know what CPU you have to give a confident answer.

Amd Ryzen 5 1600

I have plans to update to AMD Ryzen 7 pro 2700.
